# DocuSign Event Notification Errors

Tags: docusignapi

What are the different error codes we can receive from the DocuSign event notification (connect) service?

I found this document:

> https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/status-and-error-codes

Are these the errors/codes that I should expect to receive?

Answer (score 0):

This document is about making REST API calls. 
When you get a connect event, it's your web app that is being called. So DocuSign may get a bad response like 401 and 500 and if that's the case - you will see it in the Connect log which you can find in the admin web app.
But since DocuSign made the call to your app, it won't have an error code in it.